# Spawn login prompt in an X terminal

Tags: x11, login, session, terminal-emulator

I have a system that runs a bash script when it starts (I use `/etc/init.d/rc.local` to execute it without needing to log in).

For reasons I won't go in to here, I need to launch a graphical terminal to run the script. It does things like display diagnostic messages while starting an application. The way I start everything in `rc.local` is like this

```
xinit urxvt --hold -e /path/to/script
```

After doing all its diagnostic stuff, the script launches a full screen application. When that application dies (for whatever reason) the user gets dropped back at the urxvt terminal exactly where the script left off before launching.

What I would like to happen is that when the application dies, the script launches a new urxvt terminal with a login prompt. I have tried `urxvt --ls` and `urxvt --loginShell` but every time the new terminal is launches, I get a shell with the root user logged in - obviously not idea.

How can I make it launch a login prompt with no user logged in?

Comment: "login shell with no user logged in" makes no sense: what user would the shell be running under? Anyway, I don't understand very well what you want to do but maybe you could accomplish it by having the script start a login shell with `su` as the last thing it does? I don't understand at all why you need a *new* instance of `urxvt` as this point: you need the shell to display in a different window than the application did?

Comment: If I understand correctly, a login shell is one that displays a login prompt. Thats what I want to happen after the process launched by the script dies. Instead of being dropped back at the existing terminal running the script, they should be presented with a login prompt. I've tried using `su -` but since it is being run by root (since the script is run by root) it just starts a prompt like `root@localhost:~$`

Comment: Also a new instance of `urxvt` is not necessarily needed.

Comment: The definition of a **login shell** is not an application that displays a login prompt. A login shell is a shell that reads the login-time initialization scripts like `/etc/profile` at startup time. If you want a login **prompt**, then run `login`, not a shell.

Comment: I believe you’re saying that you have a function (I’m using that term in a generic sense) that you start at system boot time, through `/etc/init.d/rc.local`, and, as a result of running that function, the system presents an interactive *shell* prompt to the user when it boots. If that’s it, you need to simply *exit* from the thing you are running from `rc.local`, and let the system take care of the login dialog. If you’re starting an X session, that means you need to terminate the X session. (Or are you saying that you want a different login dialog from the one the system normally uses?)

Comment: There is a reason it has to be done graphically with X. The system is connected to an unusual display that cannot be driven by the video signal output by the system. It's only when X is launched that the correct video signal can be sent and the user can see what is going on. So killing X is not an option in this case.

Comment: So therefore yes, a different login dialog is required, I assume.

Comment: I don’t understand. Are you saying that, if you delete your thing from `/etc/init.d/rc.local`, it is no longer possible to login to the console *at all* (and the only way to login is via the network)? If yes, you have a problem that is far bigger than the question that you are asking. If no, what’s wrong with terminating the X server *after “that application dies (for whatever reason)”* (quoting from your question)? If you were able to login from the console before you created your `/etc/init.d/rc.local` thing, but that console login interface is unacceptable to you, please explain.

Comment: While I work on this, I use SSH, or I connect a regular display that will work. But the machine will not always be on a network and definitely won't always have a conventional display, so it's important that there is some easy way of accessing a console.

Comment: As an aside, can't you just make the program you are running automatically restart by wrapping in a simple shell script while(1) /path/to/script kind of thing ?